# Get models ordered by an attribute that belongs to its OneToOne model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Let's say there is one model named `User` and the other named `Pet` which has a `OneToOne` relationship with `User`, the `Pet` model has an attribute `age`, how to get the ten `User` that owns the top ten `oldest` dog?

```
class User(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

class Pet(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
     owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

---

In `User`, there is an attribute `friends` that has a `ManyToMany` relationship with `User`, how to get the ten `friends` of `User Tom` that owns the top ten `oldest` dog?

```
class User(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
     friends = models.ManyToManyField(self, ...)

class Pet(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
     owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the double-underscore syntax.

```
User.objects.order_by('-pet__age')[:10]
```

**Edit**

To get the ten friends of Tom, you can get the instance and filter:

```
User.objects.get(name='Tom').friends.order_by('-pet__age')[:10]
```

or if you already have Tom:

```
tom.friends.order_by('-pet__age')[:10]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just edited the question, could you help with the new one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :
First define **unicode** in model User like this:
By this,User model objects will always return name field of the user records.

```
 class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(self, ...)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

Then use this query:

```
   User.objects.filter(friends='Tom').order_by('-pet__age')[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (alternative to `order_by`) is using `nlargest` function of `heapq` module, this might be better if you already have `friends` list (tom's friends in this case) with a large number of items (I mean from performance perspective).

```
import heapq

heapq.nlargest(
    10,
    User.objects.get(name='Tom').friends.all(),
    key=lambda f: f.pet.age
)
```

**Note:** You have also `nsmallest` function that you can use to get the youngest pets.